# Zoom in to an image while running getpts to mark correctly in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, zooming, image-segmentation, edge-detection

I am marking the edge points on an image. The size is large, and hence marking the correct edge is difficult on my screen. I use 'getpts' to mark points. 
I want to do the following:
1. Mark the points in first iteration approximately.
2. Move the marked points closer to the correct position in second run because if I were to zoom in, marking will be difficult even though the edges are clear.

Till now it has been trial and error method. Is there a better way?

Comment: Did you try to run edge detection and it didn't work so well? And this is the reason you are trying to do it manually.

Comment: Yes. I am trying for the edge detection.

Comment: have you tried runing imedge in matalb?